# Create pdf using node.js and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have an issue with pdf generation.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
const hbs = require("handlebars");
const data = require("./database.json");
const { v4 } = require("uuid");

const compile = async function(templateName, data) {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "views", `${templateName}.hbs`);
  const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
  return hbs.compile(html)(data);
};

async function createPDF(data) {
  try {
    const pdfFileName = v4();
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(data); <-- object
    const content = await compile("index", data); <--- problem here
    await page.setContent(content);
    await page.emulateMedia("screen");
    await page.pdf({
      path: path.join(__dirname, `pdfs/${pdfFileName}.pdf`),
      format: "A4",
      printBackground: true
    });
    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

Everything works fine. I can generate my new pdf file, but for some reason, my data object in handlebars templates is `undefined`.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Who is calling createPDF()?

Comment: In the future it will be service for .net application, but now i call this function manually
```createPDF(data);```

Comment: I had exactly the same setup, i.e. generate HTML with Handlebars into a PDF and in the end I used this library for it https://www.pdfgenerator.cloud